# Counting folders with Powershell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting

Does anybody know a **powershell 2.0** command/script to count all folders and subfolders (recursive; no files) in a specific folder ( e.g. the number of all subfolders in  C:\folder1\folder2)?

In addition I also need also the number of all "leaf"-folders. in other words, I only want to count folders, which don't have subolders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `get-childitem -recurse` to get all the files and folders in the current folder.

Pipe that into `Where-Object` to filter it to only those files that are containers.

```
$files = get-childitem -Path c:\temp -recurse 
$folders = $files | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }
Write-Host $folders.Count
```

As a one-liner:

```
(get-childitem -Path c:\temp -recurse | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }).Count
```

Answer (score 19):

In PowerShell 3.0 you can use the Directory switch:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path <path> -Directory -Recurse -Force).Count
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of your question, of getting the leaf folder count, just modify the where object clause to add a non-recursive search of each directory, getting only those that return a count of 0:

```
(dir -rec | where-object{$_.PSIsContainer -and ((dir $_.fullname | where-object{$_.PSIsContainer}).count -eq 0)}).Count
```

it looks a little cleaner if you can use powershell 3.0:

```
(dir -rec -directory | where-object{(dir $_.fullname -directory).count -eq 0}).count
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
(ls -force -rec | measure -inp {$_.psiscontainer} -Sum).sum
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty good starting point:

```
(gci -force -recurse | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }).Count
```

However, I suspect that this will include `.zip` files in the count.  I'll test that and try to post an update...

**EDIT:** Have confirmed that zip files are *not* counted as containers.  The above should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Get the path child items with recourse option, pipe it to filter only containers, pipe again to measure item count

```
((get-childitem -Path $the_path -recurse | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }) | measure).Count
```