# Powershell : Quickly count containers

Tags: powershell, count, directory

I think we all know the PsIsContainer method to check if the current file is a folder or not. But in my project I need a way to quickly know the number of folders in a folder. All I need is to quickly get their number. I want to write in a .txt lines which would look like `C:\folder;12`. It would mean in the folder, with the -recurse argument, there would be 12 folders.

To explain why, I need to save the progress of my work when i cut off the program which is used to analyse some folders. When a folder's analysed, the result is written in a second .txt. For example, if a folder is called C:\folder\folder1, folder will be analysed and then folder1 will be too. Which makes folder appear 2 times in the file because the full name always is written. What i want to do is to count the number of lines where C:\folder is written. If it equals the number next it's path in the first .txt, it means the file already has been analysed and the function doesnt need to do it again.

Does someone have a solution ? Or maybe an another idea to save the progress ? Cause i really have the feeling this is taking too long to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934106/counting-folders-with-powershell)

Comment: Problem is that with this solution, i only can count folders, i cant (or i dont know how) put another condition in the where-object cmdlet. For example, i want to put a condition checking if my function returns a number greater than a certain threshold, how could i do it ?
`$i=(gci -force -recurse | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer (function1 -gt $threshold) }).Count` doesnt work.
EDIT : Okay, I hate myself for this one. I got it, nevermind.
But the program execution still is way too long

Comment: To speed it up you'd better use `Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -Directory`, the switch `-Directory` is available from PowerShell 3.0 I believe.

Comment: @Kikopu Resumption based on count is tricky, you might have a situation where a folder named "a" is created in C:\folder since your last run, how do you decide whether or not you've processed it if all you know is the count of folders in C:\folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, which i find much faster is using cmd built-in 'dir' command
of course this is in case you don't need the subfolders(which you can then run the function in a foreach loop, or change the function if this is the case)

```
Function Get-FolderCount($path)
{
$Dir = cmd /c dir $path /a:d
Return ($Dir[-1] -csplit 'Dir' -replace '\s')[0]
}
```

I use this as well for measuring folder size with /s switch and take the total size which is much faster then powershell, also much faster then run it on interactive shell...